# Yii : Facebook style url route

Tags: url-rewriting, yii

I would like to set up my Yii webapp so that the url

/username will show the user record for that user.

I've tried

```
'<username>'=> 'user/view'
```

, but this results in an error 400.

```
'<id:\d+>'=> 'user/view'
```

works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to work out what I was doing wrong.

The variables that you put in your url routes need to correspond to the functions in your controller actions.

So I changed the standard actionView generated by gii to

```
    public function actionView($username) {
         $model=User::model()->find("username = '".$username."'");
     $this->render('view',array('model'=>$model);
     }
```

Now . . . `'<username>'=> 'user/view'` as a url route works as expected .