# Is there a way to write a URL rule in Yii to redirect all requests to non-existing controllers to an existing one?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, yii, yii-routing

I need to be able to access user profiles via www.website.com/username. I have no idea how to write a rule for the rule manager to work this way. I would have a UserProfile controller to which i would like the first parameter of the url to be redirected to. Is there a way to say to the router that if he doesn't find a controller by the requested name, to execute the UserProfile controller with the rest of the parameters?

here's my current settings:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'login' => 'site/login',
            'signup/confirm/<code>' => 'signup/confrim'
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369656/yii-facebook-style-url-route

Answer (score 0):

try this. i assume you have profile controller with name UserProfileController.php

```
'<username:\w+>'=> 'userProfile/view'
```